# apkデバッグビルドしたパッケージから音が出ません

Tags: android, monaca

お世話になっております。

monacaでAndroidアプリを作成しています。
実機デバッガーでは音が再生されましたが、パッケージをデバッグビルド作成して実行してみると、apkパッケージからは音が出ません。他のアプリからは音が出ますので、本体の故障などではありません。

Androidアプリの設定では、WebViewエンジンをハイパフォーマンスに変更して、ビルドしてみましたが、それでも音が出ません。
不思議に思って、サポートで紹介されていたスクリプトをそのまま使ってみましたが、これも音が出ません。

スクリプトを以下に掲載しておきますが、なにか改善する箇所はありますでしょうか。

なお、テストしてみた端末は
Sony Xperia tablet S1(Android 4.1.1)
asus Nexus 7 (Android 5.1.1)
です。

よろしくお願いします。

```
    <script>
    ons.bootstrap();

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    //Androidではプロジェクト中にあるmp3ファイルを読み込ませるために絶対パスを指定します。そのための関数です。
    function getPath() {
        var str = location.pathname;
        var i = str.lastIndexOf('/');
        return str.substring(0,i+1);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.alert("PhoneGapの読み込みが完了しました。");
    }

    var media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    //再生するための関数です
    function playAudio() {


        var src = 'beep1.mp3';


        media = new Media (getPath() + src , onSuccess, onError);

        //再生します。{numberOfLoops:"infinite"}をつけることでループ再生させることができます。
        media.play({numberOfLoops:"infinite"});

        if (mediaTimer == null) {

            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {

                // 再生位置を返します
                media.getCurrentPosition(

                    //成功時のコールバック関数です
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");

                                    //端末によっては再生位置が-0.001で止まるので、その場合は再度読み込みます。
                                    if(position == -0.001){

                                        media.play({numberOfLoops:"infinite"});

                                    }
                        }
                    },
                    //失敗時のコールバック関数です
                    function(e) {

                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);

                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    //再生を一時停止する関数です
    function pauseAudio() {

        if (media) {
            media.pause();
        }
    }

    //再生を停止させるための関数です
    function stopAudio() {

        if (media) {
            media.stop();
        }

        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

      //成功時のコールバック関数です。ここではデバッグログに成功したことをメッセージとして出力します
      function onSuccess() {
          console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
      }

      //失敗時のコールバック関数です
      function onError(error) {
          alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
      }

      //オーディオの再生位置です
      function setAudioPosition(position) {
          document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
      }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

MonacaクラウドIDEから`ファイル`→`Cordovaプラグインの管理`と選択し、`Media`プラグインを有効にして再度ビルドしてください。
`Media`プラグインを有効・無効で確認を行い、有効にした場合にMP3が再生されました。

ほかの機能についても、Monacaデバッガーではうまく動作するのにビルドすると動作しない場合は、だいたいCordovaプラグインを有効にすると解決するようです。

Comment: 「Cordovaプラグインの管理」というものがあったのですね。
さっそく、Mediaプラグインを有効にして再ビルドしてみたところ、音が再生されました。非常に助かりました。勉強になりました。